# Change bottom navigation bar color in ionic 5

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I can't change the bottom navigation bar color of my app. When I'm changing my app theme to dark, the theme of bottom navigation bar (where overview, home and back buttons are present) remains light i.e. background is still white with black icons. How to style the bottom navigation bar in ionic?
Here's my `changeTheme()` method code where I'm changing the theme of my app:

```
changeTheme() {
    this.darkTheme = !this.darkTheme;
    if (this.darkTheme) {
      // Change app theme
      document.body.setAttribute('theme-color', 'dark');
      // Change StatusBar theme
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({ color: 'black' });
      StatusBar.setStyle({style: StatusBarStyle.Dark});
      // How to change Bottom Navigation Bar theme?
    } else {
      // Change app theme
      document.body.setAttribute('theme-color', 'light');
      // Change StatusBar theme
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({ color: 'white' });
      StatusBar.setStyle({style: StatusBarStyle.Light});
      // How to change Bottom Navigation Bar theme?
    }
  }
```

I know the question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257242/ionic-cordova-change-android-navigation-bar-color). But the solution isn't working in ionic's latest versions.

Comment: Use this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib This plugin is used to style status bar not navbar. I've already styled status bar in my code and I wanna change navbar styling.

Comment: @Mayank Kataria Have you seen my answer? I have been using the navigation bar cordova plugin, its working properly until now. You just to need to use window.NavigationBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#FF0000") or declaring a global variable of (NavigationBar) in Angular

Comment: @SnowBases Yes I tried it and its working fine now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Original answer given by @SnowBases over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64515739/11704899)

Steps:

1. Install cordova-plugin-navigationbar-color plugin with `npm i cordova-plugin-navigationbar-color`
2. Remember to implement this plugin after `platform.ready()`
3. Implementation:

```
changeTheme() {
    // StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({overlay: true});
    this.darkTheme = !this.darkTheme;
    if (this.darkTheme) {
      // Change app theme
      document.body.setAttribute('theme-color', 'dark');
      // Change StatusBar theme
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({ color: 'black' });
      StatusBar.setStyle({ style: StatusBarStyle.Dark });
      // Change NavigationBar theme
      NavigationBar.backgroundColorByName('black', false);
    } else {
      // Change app theme
      document.body.setAttribute('theme-color', 'light');
      // Change StatusBar theme
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({ color: 'white' });
      StatusBar.setStyle({ style: StatusBarStyle.Light });
      // Change NavigationBar theme
      NavigationBar.backgroundColorByName('white', true);
    }
  }
```

4. For resolving an error `Cannot find name 'NavigationBar'` declare NavigationBar as a global property outside a class like this:

```
declare const NavigationBar: any;
```